# Load alternate CSS when Javascript/JQuery is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been doing a lot of searching and haven't quite found the solution to my problem.

What I'm trying to do, is have two CSS style sheets for a website.  One style sheet for when javascript or jQuery is enabled, and one for when it is disabled.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 9):

Use something like this:

```
<noscript>
<link type="text/css" href="noscript.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</noscript>
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

For when JS *is* enabled, just create the `<link>` tag using JS. (`document.write(...);`)

Comment: I'd advise *against* `document.write()` since this will unnecessarily delay styling while the script *then* styles are loaded resulting in a much longer delay for the user.

Answer (score 3):

Your second stylesheet can just override whatever is in the first.  Past (after) that, just include the second inside a `<noscript>` tag, like this:

```
<noscript>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyles.css">
</noscript>
```